# Show all users with "disconnected" state

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I need powershell script which show me all users on server in disconnected state. I tried googling but with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`quser /server:serverName` is the command you are looking for, you could further parse it with PowerShell pretty easily. I don't think there's a more native way.

```
$username = @()
$sessions = @()
$output = (quser /server:$serverName | select -Skip 1).substring(1)
foreach ($line in $output) {
    if ($line -match 'disc') {
    $username += ($line -split '\s+')[0]
    $sessions += ($line -split '\s+')[2]
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to logout disconnected users:

```
foreach ($session in $sessions) {
            logoff $session /server:$Servername
        }
```

Comment: Ok this works, but how I can select only USERNAME and STATE column which equals "Disc"?

Comment: like so. don't forget to mark the post as answer ;)

Comment: when I add Write-Output $output it still gives me all columns.

Comment: well, users are in `$username` variable, just read the answer